# How to use Rewrite Tag Parameters in URL-rewritten Page's Titles (META & H1)?

Tags: plugins, url-rewriting

I'm developing a plugin which creates a page and inserts shortcodes as content upon plugin activation.

My goal is to have dynamic page URLs such as the following with data/content pulled from custom DB tables which will be output in the shortcodes:

domain.com/foods/{foodtype}/{foodname}

https://domain.com/foods/fruit/cherry

https://domain.com/foods/fruit/apple

https://domain.com/foods/vegetable/spinach

https://domain.com/foods/vegetable/peas

I have the following code in the plugin main file to setup rewrite rules:

```
function my_rewrite_rules() {

    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^(foods)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?',
        'index.php?pagename=foods&foodtype=$matches[2]&foodname=$matches[3]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action('init', 'my_rewrite_rules');
```

```
function add_rewrite_tags() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%foodtype%', '([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_tag('%foodname%', '([^&]+)');
}
add_action('init', 'add_rewrite_tags' );
```

What I'm having trouble with is, using the foodtype & foodname parameters/variables in the page's Meta Title AND Heading (H1) tags.

For example:

Foods > Fruit > Cherry

Foods > Vegetable > Spinach

I'm not sure what code to use and where.

If I use the following code in the main plugin file, it will rewrite the H1 title tag, and Post Title (as seen in Pages > All Pages), but not the Meta Title tags.

```
function new_title($title, $id) {
    $title = 'Page has id of '.$id;
    return $title;
}
add_filter('the_title', 'new_title', 10, 2);
```

I'm guessing I should call an add_filter() hook from within one of the shortcodes with the parameters needed to generate the correct titles? Thanks in advance.